# Naming sheet versions in google sheet using googlesheets4 or any other R package

Tags: r

Is there any way to save the current version of a sheet and name the version.

For example I want to automate the updating of covid data in a spreadsheet. The script runs once per day and updates a specific sheet. After updating the spreadsheet I want to name the current version depending on the day (just paste the strings).

I cant find a function or a parameter in the googlesheets4, googledrive package documentation.

Where do I look, is this possible by inserting a 'googlescript' command in the R script?